# C++ Reference - SomeType* &val vs. SomeType* val

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm solving **LeetCode 783. Minimum Distance Between BST Nodes** and I've noticed that the difference between a correct solution and an incorrect solution is a reference (`&`) at my function call, as follows:

**Correct Solution:**

```
class Solution {
public:
    void traverse(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* &curr, int &sol){
        if (root == nullptr) return;
        traverse(root->left, curr, sol);        
        if(curr) sol = min(sol, abs(root->val - curr->val));
        curr = root;
        traverse(root->right, curr, sol);
    }

    int minDiffInBST(TreeNode* root) {
        int sol = INT_MAX;
        TreeNode* curr = nullptr;
        traverse(root, curr, sol);
        return sol;
    }
};
```

**Incorrect Solution:**

```
class Solution {
public:
    void traverse(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* curr, int &sol){
        //Exactly the same as above!
};
```

As a student, this is the first time I have encountered this case related to Pointers and References. I'll appreciate any explanation of this difference.

Comment: It's not an edge case.  Assigning to a function's non-reference argument has no effect outside that function. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: Don't get confused with pointers. Think of it as the same difference as between `int sol` and `int& sol`

Comment: I'm confused because in both cases I'm passing an address. I can't understand what makes the difference here?

Comment: When you call `s.traverse(r, c, sol)` with the "correct" solution, it will operate on the variable `c`, but not on its copy. So when the function returns, `c` will contain the last value that `traverse` stored in this variable (if any).

Comment: In one case you're passing the address of a `TreeNode`. In the other you're passing a reference to an object whose value is the address of a `TreeNode`.

Comment: Without ref, when the call `traverse(root->left, curr, sol); ` returns, the curr is not updated, but with ref when the call `traverse(root->left, curr, sol); ` returns, the value of `curr` is updated to `root->left` (of current root)

Comment: Pointers are just another variable. Their value just happens to be the location of something. You can pass that something by reference through the pointer, but the pointer itself is passed by value unless you specify that the pointer is also passed by reference.

Comment: @ivaigult I think I've understand, please correct me if I'm wrong: `&c` operates on each recursive call (which will be executed from the call stack) while just `c` operated only in the specific call of the function. right?

Comment: The difference is *exactly* the same as the difference between `int` and `int&`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I understand the point :)!!!

Comment: You can write up an answer for your question though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this

```cpp
void foo(int * inner_ptr) {
   ptr++;
}

int main() {
   int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   int outer_ptr = &arr[1];
   foo(outer_ptr);
}
```

the `outer_ptr` will still be equal to `&arr[1]`.

You only changed the `inner_ptr`, the **copy** of the `outer_ptr`.

You can change the thing it points to.

```cpp
void foo(int * inner_ptr) {
   (*ptr) = 42;
}
```

But not the `outer_ptr` itself

Therefore you need either this signature: (with reference)

```cpp
void foo(int * & inner_ptr);
```

or this signature: (pointer to pointer) (in this case you would work with it differently in the function body tho)

```cpp
void foo(int * * inner_ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that without reference (`void traverse(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* curr, int &sol){...}`) `curr` value will not be updated for the future calls of the function (which will be executed from the call-stack).

But when there is a reference (`void traverse(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* &curr, int &sol){...}`) `curr` value will be updated and will be used for the next calls until termination of the program.